# iOS Sync Device Name

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, sharing, google

I have set up Google sync on my all my devices as I use the iOS Chrome app. When using the Chrome app I click on 'other devices' and my iMac device name shows up as iMac-2. I was wondering if it's possible to somehow rename/change my iMac device name. I've tried unlinking my iMac and linking it back up again but nothing has worked so far. I know it's only a small issue but it's bugging me.

Answer (score 1):

The other devices list on Chrome uses the name of the Mac given to it, or the DCHP if that fails. To change the name of the Mac, go to System Preferences → Sharing and enter your desired name in the box at the top. You may need to log out and back in for Chrome on OS X to update the name.